# Is it possible to get the a javascript variable from another file live?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, live

I am trying to make a system where I change a variable on one file, and it shows up on another without refreshing. Is this even possible?

**FILE 1 (javascript):**

```
testVar = "hi"
```

**FILE 2 (html):**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test()">click</button>
    <script>
        function test(){
            alert(testVar);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I would like to be able to change "hi" to "bye" in File 1 and have File 2 alert the new message (bye) without needing to refresh.

Comment: You could try using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon or even https://expressjs.com/but the hope of having the browser run the code without refreshing the browser will take something like HMR, as suggested by @timotgl

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but requires significant effort. "Hot Module Replacement" is your google keyword, as this is often done to ease the development of single page JS apps by automatically reloading the page or parts of it.

You would need to have a process running on your machine that watches the local file system for changes to a source code file. Then the web page needs to include a script that continuously checks (by talking to a locally running web server) if said source code file has been changed. If it has been changed, a script tag has to be inserted into the DOM that loads the updated source file. There's probably more details involved, but this is the gist of it.

Btw it's not good practice to assign variables without using the `var`, `let`, or `const` keywords.